# Ошибка с оператором if

Tags: java

```
 int q;
 boolean a, s, d, z, x, c;

 q = (int)(3*Math.random());
 if (q = 0) { // здесь ошибка, не пойму, в чем
     a = true;
 }
```

Comment: кнопка 101010 позволяет оформлять код

Comment: вам повезло, что пишите на Java и она ругается на это. Cи скомпилировал бы и не поморщился.

Comment: Ну насчёт не поморщился -- это не обязательно. `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value`

Comment: Для новичка этот ворнинг мало что значит )

Comment: Да привить новичку уважение к ворнингам -- задача не простая. Хорошо, если в фирме правило -- ни одного при трансляции...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас в операторе сравнения используеться оператор присвоения '=' вместо '=='.